# what is more efficient to use, console or JOptionPane?

Tags: java, input, console, integer, joptionpane

For my java class that I am taking, my professor gave us a choice of either using console or JOptionPane that performs the users choice of their geometric inputs. I was wondering if there was sort of a general consensus of what the more efficient choice would be because we can use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "efficiency". Just choose and use -- you've nothing to lose with either choice.

Comment: ok thank you, i wasnt sure